# How do I disable a button in React for just one option if the button is a reusable React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-router, components

Still learning React to the best of my ability so forgive me if this code isn't the most logical.

I have made a reusable CustomButton component in React to use across my app. I've then created 3 Card components on a Welcome page with each Card nesting this CustomButton inside of it, with each CustomButton using Link from react-router to navigate to different pages of the app. For the 3rd card, I would like to have this button disabled as this particular page will be 'coming soon'. I've been able to add a className to Link within props of the last Card to set the opacity of the text to look inactive, but want to be able to customise the entire button (not just the text within) to make it look greyed out etc.

Is there a simple way to do this?

This is my code so far:

Card:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CustomButton from './CustomButton';

const WelcomeCard = (props) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Card className='m-3 p-2 welcome-card rounded'>
        <Card.Body className='welcome-card__body'>
          <Card.Text>{props.text}</Card.Text>
          <CustomButton link={props.link} />
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default WelcomeCard;
```

CustomButton:

```
import React from 'react';

const CustomButton = (props) => {
  return <button className='custom-button'>{props.link}</button>;
};

export default CustomButton;
```

WelcomeScreen - The last component at the bottom is where I want to disable this CustomButton:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import WelcomeCard from '../components/WelcomeCard';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const WelcomeScreen = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    
        <>
          <div class='welcome-container'>
            <div>
              <h1 className='p-2 my-3 welcome-header'>Welcome</h1>
            </div>

            <div className='cards-container'>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <WelcomeCard
                    link={
                      <Link className='cards-link' to='/company'>
                        Company
                      </Link>
                    }
                  />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <WelcomeCard
                    link={
                      <Link className='cards-link' to='/landscape'>
                        Landscape
                      </Link>
                    }
                  />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <WelcomeCard
                    link={
                      <Link className='cards-link disabled-link' to='/insights'>
                        AI Insights
                      </Link>
                    }
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: can you share your `WelcomeCard` code also?

Comment: Hi @ShubhamVerma, that's the first piece of code I pasted, thanks

Comment: I mean I want to see `WelcomeCard ` . This one you pasted is `WelcomeScreen`

Comment: WelcomeCard is at the top @ShubhamVerma, pasted before CustomButton if you can see it? It's titled as 'Card:' in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use props to solve this problem?
Edit your CustomButton like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const CustomButton = (props) => {
  if(!props.active) return <button className='custom-button-disabled'></button>;
  return <button className='custom-button'>{props.link}</button>;
};

export default CustomButton;
```

You can pass this prop into the CustomButton Component now like you are doing with the link prop.

Comment: Thank you Pascal, I've edited CustomButton like you mentioned however, I'm confused in how to pass the prop into CustomButton within the WelcomeCard component in WelcomeScreen? I only want the last WelcomeCard button in WelcomeScreen to be disabled

Comment: You have got your three WelcomeCard Components in your WelcomeScreen Component. And now just add at the third component another prop like this: 

<WelcomeCard
                    link={
                      <Link className='cards-link disabled-link' to='/insights'>
                        AI Insights
                      </Link>
                    }
                  active={false}
                  />

Comment: That is a good tutorial to explain how props works in react. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component

Comment: Apologies, I missed these comments before. Great, thanks alot for your help again!